# Foreach loop on larger multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to find the correct way to use foreach loops around this multidimensional array, because what I'm doing isn't working to give me four sections.

This is one main array that breaks into another array of "Areas". There are four areas each with its own set of displays and each display has a page and expiration date.

I'm simply trying to loop each level so that I can echo different bits of data throughout the page as I need

```
$pages = array(
  "Areas" => array(
    "Area One"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby"=>array(
          "Page"=>"News",
          "Expiration"=>"06/12/2018"
        ),
        "Office"=>array(
          "Page"=>"Social",
          "Expiration"=>"06/30/2018"
        ),
      ),
    ),
    "Area Two"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby"=>array(
          "Page"=>"News",
          "Expiration"=>"06/12/2018"
        ),
        "Office"=>array(
          "Page"=>"Social",
          "Expiration"=>"06/30/2018"
        ),
      ),
    ),
    "Area Three"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby"=>array(
          "Page"=>"News",
          "Expiration"=>"06/12/2018"
        ),
        "Office"=>array(
          "Page"=>"Social",
          "Expiration"=>"06/30/2018"
        ),
      ),
    ),
    "Area Fou"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby"=>array(
          "Page"=>"News",
          "Expiration"=>"06/12/2018"
        ),
        "Office"=>array(
          "Page"=>"Social",
          "Expiration"=>"06/30/2018"
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


<?php foreach($pages as $areas=>area):?>
<h3><?php echo $area?> This would list Area One, Area Two, etc.</h3>
<h5><?php echo $Displays?>This would list Lobby, Office</h5>
<?php end foreach?>
```

So I should end up with 4 blocks of text listing each area and it's respective displays, if that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you include the code you currently have in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to imbricate two foreach here:

```
foreach($pages["Areas"] as $area_name => $area_details)
{
    echo "<h3>" . $area_name . "</h3>";
    foreach($area_details["Displays"] as $d=>$v)
    {
        echo "<h5>" . $d . "</h5>";
        echo "<p>Page: " . $v["Page"] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Expiration: " . $v["Expiration"] . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Displays` as the key for each area. The you could use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to display them as a string or [use another foreach](https://3v4l.org/fk2dk) to display them per array item.

Perhaps you could update your code like

```
<?php foreach($pages["Areas"] as $areas => $area):?>
<h5><?php echo $areas?></h5>
<h3><?php echo implode(',', array_keys($area["Displays"]))?></h3>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/IGk16)